# Can I override onCreate() function via cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

By default, after I create a cordova android project, the MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
    {
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
            loadUrl(launchUrl);
         }
      }
```

Now I need to add a line `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`
 before the `loadUrl(launchUrl)` to prevent the app go to sleep mode.
But in some reason we don't want to break the default structure, that is, can I use cordova plugin to override `onCreate()` function separately other than insert this line of code directly?

Or does anyone have an idea to achieve the goal to keep your app always in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found a solution, works fine for me.

```
    public class KeepAwake extends CordovaPlugin {
       @Override
       public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
       if (action.equals("keepAwake")) {
            this.keepAwake(callbackContext);
            return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    private void keepAwake(final CallbackContext callbackContext){
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          cordova.getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
          callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
        }
      });
    }
}
```